# CPS library for nice dataflow with Scala 2.10 futures

Tags: scala, future, continuations

I am looking for a light weight library that allows me, instead of writing:

```
val future1 = process1()
future1.onSuccess { process2() }
```

the following:

```
val future1 = process1()
future1.await()
process2()
```

*without blocking* the thread (so not: `Await.result(future1)`) That is, I am imagining a continuations based library which transforms the latter into the former.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only such library I know currently is **Akka DataFlow**: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dataflow.html

Looking at the project definition (https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/project/AkkaBuild.scala), it seems that akka-dataflow does not have much dependencies, so it should be pretty lightweight.

**UPDATE:**
Here's an example use, taken from akka-dataflow's documentation:

```
flow {
  val f1 = flow { "Hello" }
  val f2 = flow { "world!" }
  f1() + " " + f2()
} onComplete println
```

Which clearly illustrate that you can write your code in a procedural way (even though under the hood this really is transformed into a map/flatMap chain).

As **another smple alternative**, have you considered just using for continuations? They are bit more verbose to use, but the general benefit is the same: writing your code procedurally instead of cluttering it with explicit cps-style. By example, the above example directly translates to the following pure scala code:

```
{for {
  f1 <- future( "Hello" );
  f2 <- future( "world!" )
} yield f1 + " " + f2
} onComplete println
```

Which is not that different. And you won't find a more lightweight library than **no** library (though I admit that I still prefer akka-dataflow in terms of conciseness, but only by a slight margin).

Comment: You need to put the futures in `val`s though and then use them in the for-comprehension; otherwise they run sequentially because the 2nd future doesn't even get created until the 1st one is complete.

Comment: Well that was kind of the point. You'll notice that in OP's code too the second future does not get created until the first one completes. I am pretty sure this is exactly what he wanted, but he just did not want to block a thread for it.

Answer (score 4):

Taka a look at [Akka Dataflow Concurrency](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dataflow.html). Looks like exactly what you want!

**Example** (see the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dataflow.html#Using_flow)):

```scala
flow {
  val f1 = flow { "Hello" }
  val f2 = flow { "world!" }
  f1() + " " + f2()
} onComplete println
```

Akka Dataflow uses Scala's [Delimited Continuations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation) to automatically and behind the scenes generate the continuations for you.

Comment: Dataflow concurrency is a cool idea for overcoming the limitation of the JVM (that threads are expensive) whilst writing in effect sequential code. This goes some way to achieving the benefits of Communicating Sequential Processes on the JVM, which is quite difficult to do because CSP assumes that threads are cheap, which they are in some languages. The primary benefit is WYSIWYG code - simple sequential code without the difficulties of asynchronous use of callbacks, futures etc.

Comment: To complement you, @Rick-777, the Akka Dataflow Continuation-passing style library uses lightweight Scala futures, which run _on_ threads but are _not_ (heavy) threads themselves.

Answer (score 4):

This question was asked one year ago.
Today, a more promising alternative than Akka Dataflow is **scala-async**, available at https://github.com/scala/async.

Akka Dataflow  relies on the continuation plugin which is not actively maintained and is on the path to deprecation.

On the other hand, **scala-async** does not try to be a general purpose cps solution, but only tackles the writing of asynchronous code (which I believe happens to be the most common use case of the cps plugin). 
In other words it directly implements the equivalent of Akka's `flow` method (with the help of macros), and as such has a narrower (and better defined) scope than the cps plugin, which I think is key in allowing it be a better implementation overall.

Here is an example taken from the readme page:

```
val future = async {
  val f1 = async { ...; true }
  val f2 = async { ...; 42 }
  if (await(f1)) await(f2) else 0
}
```

Comment: Good point. Personally, I am waiting for RAY (Haller & Miller) to be released :)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, I didn't know this project. This does seems interesting: http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/188383/files/directrx.pdf

Answer (score 3):

There is one more dataflow concurrency implementation in Scala, that you might want to checkout, [ScalaFLow](https://github.com/hotzen/ScalaFlow). The github repo contains the thesis PDF as well, describing the work in very good detail.

Kai gives a demo in [this forum thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/7890.html):

Quote:

"A minimal demo (yes, looks like Futures):

```
val v = new Variable[Int]
flow { println( v() ) // suspends without blocking }
flow { v := 42 // resumes above flow }
```

"

Comment: isn't that same as akka dataflow?

Comment: @KrzysztofKowalski, no, it is separate, as far as I can tell. Unfortunately also, ScalaFlow seems more or less unmaintained these days.